# Event and delegate contravariance in .NET 4.0 and C# 4.0

Tags: c#, events, delegates, c#-4.0, clr4.0

While investigating [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120506/) I got curious about how the new covariance/contravariance features in C# 4.0 will affect it.

In Beta 1, C# seems to disagree with the CLR. Back in C# 3.0, if you had:

```
public event EventHandler<ClickEventArgs> Click;
```

... and then elsewhere you had:

```
button.Click += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(button_Click);
```

... the compiler would barf because they're incompatible delegate types. But in C# 4.0, it compiles fine, because in CLR 4.0 the type parameter is now marked as `in`, so it is contravariant, and so the compiler assumes the multicast delegate `+=` will work.

Here's my test:

```
public class ClickEventArgs : EventArgs { }

public class Button
{
    public event EventHandler<ClickEventArgs> Click;

    public void MouseDown()
    {
        Click(this, new ClickEventArgs());
    }
}

class Program
{    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Button button = new Button();

        button.Click += new EventHandler<ClickEventArgs>(button_Click);
        button.Click += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(button_Click);

        button.MouseDown();
    }

    static void button_Click(object s, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Button was clicked");
    }
}
```

But although it compiles, it doesn't work at runtime (`ArgumentException`: Delegates must be of the same type).

It's okay if you only add either one of the two delegate types. But the combination of two different types in a multicast causes the exception when the second one is added.

I guess this is a bug in the CLR in beta 1 (the compiler's behaviour looks hopefully right).

**Update for Release Candidate:**

The above code no longer compiles. It must be that the contravariance of `TEventArgs` in  the `EventHandler<TEventArgs>` delegate type has been rolled back, so now that delegate has the same definition as in .NET 3.5.

That is, the beta I looked at must have had:

```
public delegate void EventHandler<in TEventArgs>(object sender, TEventArgs e);
```

Now it's back to:

```
public delegate void EventHandler<TEventArgs>(object sender, TEventArgs e);
```

But the `Action<T>` delegate parameter `T` is still contravariant:

```
public delegate void Action<in T>(T obj);
```

The same goes for `Func<T>`'s `T` being covariant.

This compromise makes a lot of sense, as long as we assume that the primary use of multicast delegates is in the context of events. I've personally found that I never use multicast delegates except as events.

So I guess C# coding standards can now adopt a new rule: don't form multicast delegates from multiple delegate types related through covariance/contravariance. And if you don't know what that means, just avoid using `Action` for events to be on the safe side.

Of course, that conclusion has implications for [the original question that this one grew from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120506/)...

Comment: Thoiugh interesting want's the question?

Comment: I am surprised this hole escaped the notice of C# team, should be one of the first things they would have tested after introducing variance for generic delegates isnt it? C# 5 exhibit it too (the clr version being the same).

Answer (score 11):

Very interesting. You don't need to use events to see this happening, and indeed I find it simpler to use simple delegates.

Consider `Func<string>` and `Func<object>`. In C# 4.0 you can implicitly convert a `Func<string>` to `Func<object>` because you can always use a string reference as an object reference. However, things go wrong when you try to combine them. Here's a short but complete program demonstrating the problem in two different ways:

```
using System;

class Program
{    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Func<string> stringFactory = () => "hello";
        Func<object> objectFactory = () => new object();

        Func<object> multi1 = stringFactory;
        multi1 += objectFactory;

        Func<object> multi2 = objectFactory;
        multi2 += stringFactory;
    }    
}
```

This compiles fine, but both of the `Combine` calls (hidden by the += syntactic sugar) throw exceptions. (Comment out the first one to see the second one.)

This is definitely a problem, although I'm not exactly sure what the solution should be. It's possible that *at execution time* the delegate code will need to work out the most appropriate type to use based on the delegate types involved. That's a bit nasty. It would be quite nice to have a generic `Delegate.Combine` call, but you couldn't really express the relevant types in a meaningful way.

One thing that's worth noting is that the covariant conversion is a reference conversion - in the above, `multi1` and `stringFactory` refer to the same object: it's *not* the same as writing

```
Func<object> multi1 = new Func<object>(stringFactory);
```

(At that point, the following line will execute with no exception.) At execution time, the BCL really does have to deal with a `Func<string>` and a `Func<object>` being combined; it has no other information to go on.

It's nasty, and I seriously hope it gets fixed in some way. I'll alert Mads and Eric to this question so we can get some more informed commentary.

Comment: Cool, I arrived at practically the same example code when tinkering with it on the train home. Would be very interesting to hear the gnarly details.

Comment: What's the status of this? I would like to use generics and variance restriction in runtime delegate instances, and I don't need the multicast capability but I would like to prevent the next developer from assuming multicasting is in play and it crashes with this mind bender.  Is there an established best practice or maybe a compiler warning that will detect this and provide a hint to use the New constructor pattern.

Comment: @AndyzSmith: There's been no change that I'm aware of, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3):

I just had to fix this in my application. I did the following:

```
// variant delegate with variant event args
MyEventHandler<<in T>(object sender, IMyEventArgs<T> a)

// class implementing variant interface
class FiresEvents<T> : IFiresEvents<T>
{
    // list instead of event
    private readonly List<MyEventHandler<T>> happened = new List<MyEventHandler<T>>();

    // custom event implementation
    public event MyEventHandler<T> Happened
    {
        add
        {
            happened.Add(value);
        }
        remove
        {
            happened.Remove(value);
        }
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        happened.ForEach(x => x.Invoke(this, new MyEventArgs<T>(t));
    }
}
```

I don't know if there are relevant differences to regular multi-cast events. As far as I used it, it works ...

By the way: [I never liked the events in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3045200/27343). I don't understand why there is a language feature, when it doesn't provide any advantages.

Comment: The primary difference is that multicast delegates are immutable, so it is thread-safe to add/remove handlers during invocation. In your implementation, the list could mutate during event invocation with unpredictable results.

Comment: @SørenBoisen: very good point. Thank you for this one. I could use a `ConcurrentBag<T>` instead of the list.

Comment: Another option is using ImmutableArray or ImmutableList from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/09/25/immutable-collections-ready-for-prime-time.aspx. That would optimize for dispatch vs add/remove, but more importantly, they are available in PCL projects :-)

Comment: great start - I'm sure it can be optimized

Comment: this actually worked (!):

        private event MyEventHandler<T> happened;
        public event MyEventHandler<T> Happvened
        {
            add => this.happened += new MyEventHandler<T>(value);
            remove => this.happened -= new MyEventHandler<T>(value);
        }

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the ArgumentException from both? If the exception is being thrown by just the new handler, then I would think that it's backward-compatible.

BTW, I think you have your comments mixed up. In C# 3.0 this:

`button.Click += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(button_Click); // old`

wouldn't have run. That's c#4.0

Comment: I've removed all references to versioning in the question, as it seems to have just caused you confusion. The comments about new and old related to the issue I was originally thinking about, which I split this question out from. This question has nothing to do with backward compatibility per se. It's about the compiler assuming that a multicast delegate can bind to methods of contravariant types, which then turns out not to be true at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The following code actually works if you have the delegates normalized to the same type from within upon attaching/detaching! I didn't expect detaching to work but it does. It may not be the most optimized solution but it is clean and simple and it solves a serious problem I've had with my Foundation where co-variance is important for example IObservableList : IObservableListOut. At some point extensions created different delegate types depending on context T where T can be 2 different interfaces per context and therefore the delegates created ended up of different type. It wasn't until today that I actually understood how this issue resulted. Detaching won't work with plain "- value".

```
    private event MyEventHandler<T> happened;
    public event MyEventHandler<T> Happened
    {
        add => this.happened += new MyEventHandler<T>(value);
        remove => this.happened -= new MyEventHandler<T>(value);
    }
```