# Adding multiple delegates to Func<T> and returning result of first lambda delegate (C#)?

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda

I want to add a lambda function to a `Func<T>`. Furthermore I would like the returned value to be that of the first lambda delegate (I cannot initially change the order the first one will always be applied first). When I try to do this with the `+=` syntax I get the following:

> Error 44  Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type '`System.Func<TEntity>`' and 'lambda expression'

How can I achieve the above? I would really like to avoid using the traditional delegate syntax if possible.

```
class Transaction
{
    static Func<TEntity> ifNullInitializeWithThisReturnedObject = () => default(TEntity);

    public static bool IsDirty { get; private set; }

    public init (Func<TEntity> IfNullInitializeWithThisReturnedObject)
    {
         ifNullInitializeWithThisReturnedObject = IfNullInitializeWithThisReturnedObject;
    }
    public void somemethod()
    {
        ifNullInitializeWithThisReturnedObject += () => 
        { 
            IsDirty = true; 
            return default( TEntity ); 
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Not related to question, but are you sure your init method is correct? Shouldn't you be swapping r/l of the assignment?

Comment: I dont see what the problem should be here. Should compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use the traditional delegate syntax, and then get the invocation list explicitly? For example:

```
delegate int fdelegate();

var f1 = new Func<int>(() => { return 1; });
var f2 = new Func<int>(() => { return 2; });

var f1d = new fdelegate(f1);
var f2d = new fdelegate(f2);
fdelegate f = f1d;
f += f2d;

int returnValue;
bool first = true;
foreach (var x in f.GetInvocationList())
{
    if (first)
    {
        returnValue = ((fdelegate)x)();
        first = false;
    }
    else
    {
        ((fdelegate)x)();
    }
}
```

Comment: Excessive syntax for the declarations there. You can reduce that to `fdelegate f = () => 1; f += () => 2;`

Answer (score 1):

+= is for events. You want a List < Func < TEntity > >. Given such a list, you could do this:

```
// funcList is an IEnumerable<Func<TEntity>> we got somehow
bool firstTime = true;
TEntity result;
foreach (f in funcList)
{
    if (firstTime)
        result = f();
    else
        f();
    firstTime = false;
}
return result;
```

Comment: This should work, but `+=` is for multicast delegates. Basically all delegates.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to use a lambda as a multicast delegate, which isn't what it is.

See this StackOverlflow question: [Use of multicast in C# multicast delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297550/use-of-multicast-in-c-multicast-delegates)

I'd advise either go back to using the Delegate syntax like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173175(v=vs.80).aspx, or use a `List<Func<TEntity>>`.

Answer (score 0):

What if you created a collection: `List<Func<TEntity>>` ?