# When should we use Action<T> and not create a custom delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

When should we use `Action<T>` and not to define a delegate explicitly?

Comment: Dupe: [creating-delegates-manually-vs-using-action-func-delegates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482613/creating-delegates-manually-vs-using-action-func-delegates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well...

```
Action<T> is almost the same as delegate void (T t)
and
Func<T> is almost the same as delegate T ()
```

Action and Func (and lambdas) are just 'syntactical sugar' and a convenience for using delegates.

So it's really just a matter of preference.

Comment: @amitkohan Yes, _almost_ the same. One thing to be aware of is contravariance of `Action<T>`. If contravariance is not desired, write your own delegate type without contravariance. See my comment to Servy's answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's entirely a matter of preference, but I see no reason to ever define your own delegate if one of the overloads of Action or Func will work.  If you have a ref/out/params parameter, optional arguments, or some other such edge cases you have no choice but to define your own.

Comment: Something else: Since .NET 4.0, `Action<in T>` is **contravariant** in `T`. But at the same time, delegate combination ("addition" of two delegate objects) doesn't work with contravariance (Lippert's words: [all messed up](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2307942/1336654)). So suppose you make a `public event Action<string> ItHappened;`. Then because of contravariance, one subscriber could add an `Action<object>` to `ItHappened`, another one an `Action<IConvertible>`, a third one `Action<ICloneable>`. That throws at runtime! So a reason to use a user-defined type is to **not** have contravariance.

Comment: While with Action/Func life is much easier, custom delegates give you better type safety (correctness). In the end there's a trade-off. Another benefit is the better (more meaningful) parameter name and IDE's documentation support.