# Combining delegates and contravariance

Tags: c#

The article states the following: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx

Variance does not apply to delegate combination. That is, given two delegates of types `Action<Derived>` and `Action<Base>` (`Action(Of Derived)` and `Action(Of Base)` in Visual Basic), you cannot combine the second delegate with the first although the result would be type safe. Variance allows the second delegate to be assigned to a variable of type `Action<Derived>`, but delegates can combine only if their types match exactly.

```
Action<B> baction = (taret) => { Console.WriteLine(taret.GetType().Name); };
Action<D> daction = baction;
Action<D> caction = baction + daction;
```

In the above code `baction` and `daction` take different parameters. But still I am able to combine them.
What am I missing?

TIA.

Comment: In your example, `baction` and `daction` are references to the same object. Therefore `baction.GetType() == daction.GetType()` certainly, because it's the same instance. Problem arises when the two delegate objects are distinct and have different runtime types. Now, _before_ .NET 4.0, for every delegate object the runtime type and the compiletime type agreed, because delegates were (sealed types and) invariant. But in .NET 4.0 and C# 4, and later, a compiletime `Action<string>` could runtime be `Action<object>`, `Action<ICloneable>`, `Action<IEnumerable<char>>`, and so on.

Comment: Close: [event-and-delegate-contravariance-in-net-4-0-and-c-sharp-4-0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120688/event-and-delegate-contravariance-in-net-4-0-and-c-sharp-4-0)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation is not clear, I agree.

The problem is that the *runtime* types of two combined delegates must match.  Which means that there are scenarios where the *compile time* types match, but the *runtime* types do not.

Consider for example:

```
Func<string> f1 = ()=>"";
Func<object> f2 = ()=>null;
Func<object> f3 = f1; // legal in C# 4 because of covariance
Func<object> f4 = f2 + f3;
```

That's legal at compile time; you're adding two delegates of the same compile-time type. But at runtime it will fail because the *runtime* requires that the *runtime types* exactly match.

This is an unfortunate hole in the CLR type system. I'm hoping we can get it fixed some day, but no promises.

Comment: You diplomatically failed to point out that the part that is working now is the part that _you_ were responsible for.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that part of the difficulty is that there isn't necessarily a way of inferring the best type?  Both Action<Action<Cat>> and Action<Action<Dog>> derive from Action<Action<Animal>>, and one could certainly write code which, given T and two delegates deriving from Action<Action<T>>, would produce an Action<Action<T>> which performed both actions sequentially.  Given an Action<Action<Cat>> and Action<Action<Dog>>, however, there would be no way for the system to know without being told that the combined delegate should be an Action<Action<Animal>>.

Comment: @supercat: first off, just to be precise: Action<Action<Cat>> *derives from* System.MulticastDelegate. It is *implicitly convertible via reference conversion* to Action<Action<Animal>>. Nit-pickiness aside, yes, you have identified a genuine problem here.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Point taken on derivation versus convertibility.  In some ways, I wish delegates were an interface rather than class type; such a design would, however, be useless without generics, and by the time generics were added to .net 2.0, delegates were already well established.  If delegates were an interface type, something like a closure would only require the creation of one object instance rather than two.  I wonder what the broader implications of such a design would have been?

Comment: @EricLippert why is it required that runtime types should match? What could go wrong if calling `f4` is to merely execute `f2` followed by `f1` and return result of `f1`?

Comment: @nawfal: It's not a *logical* problem, it is an *implementation* problem. Basically, the code in the CLR that deals with delegate combinations does not handle these sorts of covariant scenarios well.