# Why do .NET events have a sender parameter of type object and not of type T?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, event-handling

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [In a C# event handler, why must the "sender" parameter be an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437699/in-a-c-event-handler-why-must-the-sender-parameter-be-an-object)
>   [Event Signature in .NET — Using a Strong Typed 'Sender'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046016/event-signature-in-net-using-a-strong-typed-sender)

Why do all of the events in .NET have their first parameter as of type `object`, and not of a generic type `T`? Every time I have to get my sender, I have to typecast it to some more derived type. For example:

```
(Button)sender
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046016/event-signature-in-net-using-a-strong-typed-sender

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the universal signature of event handler methods was invented long before generics were ever added to the language.

Using [`System.Object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx) was the logical choice in the days before generics, as it really was the most "generic" object available. All other objects ultimately derive from `System.Object`, including controls, BCL classes, and user-defined classes, because it is at the root of the type hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

The first reason is that this design pre-dates the introduction of generics.

But what do you think a generic approach would look like?  In WinForms an OnClick event can be triggered by a Button as well as by a MenuItem. A MenuItem is not even a Control.

This event signature is used through-out the .NET library, so *sender* could really be anything, not just a Control or other GUI element. And the mos common class is ... `System.Object`.

You will have to type-cast.

Answer (score 2):

Strongly types senders don't work too well with inheritance hierarchies.

```
public class Base
{
  public event EventHandler<Base,MyEventArgs> MyEvent;
}

public class Derived:Base
{

}
```

Now you want to subscribe on `Derived` to `MyEvent`. Your sender will only be `Base`. One could work around this with `new`, but that gets ugly.