# How to create a fade-in animation for a newly created control in C# UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, uwp

So, simple question but I can't figure it out right now. In my C# XAML UWP app I am loading a series of photos. I'm wanting to animate a fade-in for each newly created photo. The photo objects are created in the code-behind as follows.

```
//getting the photos into the scroller
foreach (StorageFile current_file in GlobalVars.glo_lst_image_files)
{
    Image current_image = new Image();
    BitmapImage current_bitmapimage = new BitmapImage();
    await current_bitmapimage.SetSourceAsync(await current_file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read));
    current_bitmapimage.DecodePixelWidth = image_width;
    current_image.Source = current_bitmapimage;
    current_image.Width = image_width;

    current_image.Style = App.Current.Resources["ImagePhotoScroller"] as Style;
    current_image.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(OnPhotoScrollerImageLoad);

    stack_photoscroller.Children.Add(current_image);
}
```

The idea is that `OnPhotoScrollerImageLoad` will start a fade-in storyboard on the photo's `Loaded` event. How to accomplish this is where I'm having difficulty. I've tried a few things.

I've tried to create the entire animation in C# as follows.

```
private void OnPhotoScrollerImageLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var storyboard = new Storyboard();
    var doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
    doubleAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
    doubleAnimation.EnableDependentAnimation = true;
    doubleAnimation.From = 0;
    doubleAnimation.To = 1;

    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, "Opacity");
    Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation, sender);
    storyboard.Children.Add(doubleAnimation);
    storyboard.Begin();
}
```

I was unable to get the target right. I would get an error when using `sender`. In my previous apps I would only animate pre-existing objects which were named in XAML. I am unsure how to correctly set this parameter.

I also tried to make the animation in XAML as follows.

```
<Storyboard x:Name="PhotoScrollerImageLoadFade">
    <DoubleAnimation x:Name="PhotoScrollerImageLoadFade_dblanim" 
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                        From="0" To="1" 
                        Duration="0:0:1"/>
</Storyboard>
```

and then set the target in C#

```
private void OnPhotoScrollerImageLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Storyboard.SetTarget(PhotoScrollerImageLoadFade_dblanim, sender);
    PhotoScrollerImageLoadFade.Begin();
}
```

But again, the `sender` isn't working. How should I achieve this?

Comment: Which error? Did you try using casting `(DependencyObject)sender` ?

Comment: @Sinatr I guess I should have included, it was "cannot convert from 'object' to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject'". Your solution worked perfectly. I knew it was gonna be something simple. If you write a proper solution I could mark yours as correct.

Answer (score 0):

> cannot convert from 'object' to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject

All events have `sender` parameter defined as `object` (do not ask me [why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1437699/1997232)).

In [`Loaded`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded(v=vs.110).aspx) event `sender` is [`FrameworkElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement(v=vs.110).aspx). [`Storyboard.SetTarget`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190498(v=vs.95).aspx) require `DependencyObject`, so you can simply cast `sender` to it (`FrameworkElement` inherits from `DependencyObject`):

```
Storyboard.SetTarget(someTimeline, (DependencyObject)sender);
```