# Action<object, EventArgs> could not be cast to EventHandler?

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling, casting

I was wiring up an event to use a lambda which needed to remove itself after triggering. I couldn't do it by inlining the lambda to the += event (no accessable variable to use to remove the event) so i set up an `Action<object, EventArgs>` variable and moved the lambda there. The main error was that it could not convert an `Action<object, EventArgs>` to an EventHandler. I thought lambda expressions were implicitly convertable to event handlers, why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Lambdas are implicitly convertible to delegate types with the right shape, but two same-shaped delegate types are not implicitly convertible to one another.  Just make the local variable have type EventHandler instead.

```
EventHandler h = (o, ea) => { ... };
e += h;
...
e -= h;
```

(in case it helps:

```
Action<object, EventArgs> a = (o, ea) => { }; 
EventHandler e = a;  // not allowed
EventHandler e2 = (o,ea) => a(o,ea);  // ok
```

)

Comment: Except that e2 now goes through two function calls to actually do anything... eww.

Comment: I'm not promoting e2 as a good way to write code, I'm just using it as an example to demonstrate what is and is not legal with regards to the C# type system.

Comment: @Matthew Scharley - have you measured the overhead?

Comment: It strikes me as a bit silly that you can't cast from one delegate type to another that is equivalent. Is there any good reason for this?

Comment: @Snarfblam: I'm guessing it's the covariance issue, as delegates are generics. I wonder if this issue has gone in .NET 4.

Comment: @Cameron - it has not. The new 4.0 covariance translates between `Func<string>` and `Func<object>` where appropriate, but that is because they are both kinds of `Func<T>` delegate. If they used a different named delegate type, they would be incompatible. The simple solution is to always use `Func` or `Action` to represent delegates. They allow up to 8 parameters in 4.0. The only limitation of them is that they don't allow the parameters to be `out` or `ref`, which is possible with custom named delegate types.

Comment: On whether there is much value in using custom delegate types for events, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120506/what-would-i-lose-by-abandoning-the-standard-eventhandler-pattern-in-net

Comment: @MatthewScharley - OTOH, the traditional `handler += myMethod` actually compiles into `handler += new EventHandler(myMethod)` - so the overhead is perhaps not that different.

Answer (score 53):

```
Action<Object, EventArgs> a = (o, ea) => { };
EventHandler e = a.Invoke;
```

Comment: This should be the answer. Nice!

Answer (score 3):

Declare your event as

```
public event Action<object, EventArgs> e;
```

Then you can directly add your action:

```
Action<object, EventArgs> a = something;
e += a;
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, delegates can't be cast because they have no inheritance tree defining which casts are valid. To that end, you have two choices:

1. Use a variable of type `EventHandler` instead of the `Action<T1, T2>`
2. Use an inline declaration.

   ```
   // option 1: local variable
   EventHandler eh = (o, ea) => { /* [snip] */ };
   obj.event += eh;
   obj.event -= eh;

   // option 2: inline declaration
   obj.event += (o, ea) => { /* [snip] */ };
   ```

Comment: The whole point of using a variable was so that i could remove the event from the event handler while still inside the event. Still, +1.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an anonymous method instead:

```
Event += (sender, e) =>
{
     // Multiple lines
     // of code here
};
```

Comment: That's the whole point.... I have one set up only stored into a variable to i can have the event remove itself when fired, only it won't work.