# C# has to subscribe to an event before event called

Tags: c#

I want to implement a fast way to add listener to an event, my implementation:

```
public class AccountManager 
{

    public delegate void CheckIfLoggedInListener(EventArgs e);
    public event CheckIfLoggedInListener SetCheckIfLoggedInListener;

    public void CheckIfLoggedIn()
    {                
         if(SetCheckIfLoggedInListener!=null)
             SetCheckIfLoggedInListener(new EventArgs("e"));
    }
}
```

Right now, I have to set listener first, then invoke the method, which can be easily messed up if other developer doesn't pay attention:

```
//this will not work, because you invoke the event before subscribing
accountManager.CheckIfLoggedIn();
accountManager.SetCheckIfLoggedInListener += (e) => { Debug.Log(e.param); };
```

I wonder if there is a way to make the order  not mandatory?

Comment: This is *how* events work. The idea is to only fire the event *if* there's something to fire.

Comment: If event listener is not attached then how do you expect the code to work? Do you want the code to generate the listener if not already attached? If the programming has to be done as per the developer's will then exception handing is not at all needed. You shouldn't write bad code just coz developer doesn't want to pay attention.

Comment: If you're worried about others not using events properly, don't. If they are any good they'll subscribe to your events properly. Besides, the behavior that you want can be harmful. What if adding a listener to an event after it is called is *intentional*? What if the listener shouldn't be called for, say, the first time the method is called, but should be called for every subsequent method call?
As a library developer, trying to "work around" *such* kinds of potential mistakes is a waste of time, and can even harm those who actually know what they are doing.

Comment: by the way, your code may not work properly in any case.  Assign to a local first, then check for null.

 var evt = SetCheckIfLoggedInListener;

if(evt!=null)
    evt(new EventArgs("e"));

Comment: @cineammispelt Alternatively, in newer version of .NET, you can use `SetCheckIfLoggedInListener?.Invoke(new EventArgs("e"));` which is a little nicer. VS2015 (and maybe older versions) will actually suggest re-factoring the older event dispatch pattern into this alternate versions.

Comment: @ozeanix according to this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928077/event-invokeargs-vs-eventargs-which-is-faster, this seems they are only different compile version?

Comment: @ywj7931 The difference is the speculative call of `Invoke` only if the event is not `null`, which happens when an event has no subscribers. Instead of having to pull the event value to a local variable, then do an if test, then invoke the event, you can simply use `?.Invoke()` to do it in one line. You can't do `event(new EventArgs("e"))` because event could be null and you'd throw an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a parameter of generic delegate that will be object of type [`Action<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) and in your case it would be`Action<EventArgs>` in your method to make sure that:

### EDIT:

you would need to tweak it to work, instead of `Action<EventArgs>`, we would have to use `Action<Object,EventArgs>`, [this post explains why is that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551953/actionobject-eventargs-could-not-be-casted-to-eventhandler)

```
public void CheckIfLoggedIn(Action<object,EventArgs> action)
{
    SetCheckIfLoggedInListener = action.Invoke;

     if(SetCheckIfLoggedInListener!=null)
         SetCheckIfLoggedInListener(null,new EventArgs());
}
```

and when calling you would need to do like:

```
//this will not work, because you invoke the event before subscribing
accountManager.CheckIfLoggedIn((o,e) => { Console.WriteLine("event fired");  });
```

[Working **DEMO Fiddle** here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RQhfKz)

This way you can make it mandatory for user to register the implementation to be called when event is fired.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This looks like exactly what am I looking for! Since I want to combine those two lines into one line. I will try this!

Comment: So I can even add this.SetCheckIfLoggedInListener -= action at the end of the function to prevent memory leak, right?

Comment: I got the error, "cannot implicaitly convert type 'System.Action<EventArgs> to 'CheckIfLoggedInListener' ", any chance you know why?

Comment: I have update the post with the compilable code and with reference why we need to do like this.